# How to make a tutorial for my android application?

Tags: android, icons

I want to make a tutorial(user guide) for my Android application that informs users how to use the application. I saw many applications that use animations to direct users how to learn to use the application step by step.

I searched but I couldn't find how to do that. Do you have any tutorial that helps me or which keywords I should search with? I want to make a guide positioning to the icon or button; first to do it and informs what is it for.

Comment: In the ApiDemos (Sample Android Projects) there's some examples that can help you.

Answer (score 18):

Take a look at this library: https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView I think it's a good fit for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/onboarding, to do and onboarding when the users use your app for the first time.

Comment: Isn't this mainly for Android TV?